# Recursively get index of substring start in string in C++

Tags: c++, string, recursion, substring

Given the function:

```
int getIndex(string mystring, string substring);
```

How do I find the index of `mystring` where `substring` begins, if there is one? I don't want to use the default `find` function, I want to make my own (in C++). My find method return true if an occurrence of that substring exists.

I have the following thoughts so far:

```
int getIndex(string mystring, string substring)
{
    if(find(mystring, substring))
        return counter();
return -1;
}
int counter()
{
        int count; //I'm not sure how to use this value without a global
                     //variable or variable declared in main()
        ++count;
}
```

Comment: There is no reason why you would possibly want to reimplement a `std::string` function from scratch.

Comment: Sure there is, learning and practice.

Comment: If you can find the substring, you should be able to find the location it starts.

Comment: YOu are still using find

Comment: @VectorCroc: The world of C++ programming is full of people who have irrational reasons for not using the standard library. If it's just for learning, fair enough, then, but you should always make sure to specify that in your question. Otherwise, I'll automatically be in code-review mood :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an overloaded function that does the real work and make it recursive. Call the second function from the first with a starting index.

```
int getIndex(char const* mystring, size_t len1,
             char const* substring, size_t len2, int index)
{
   if ( len1 < len2 )
   {
      return -1;
   }

   if ( strncmp(mystring, substring, len2) == 0)
   {
     return index;
   }

   return getIndex(mystring+1, len1-1, substring, len2, index+1);   
}

int getIndex(string mystring, string substring)
{
   return getIndex(mystring.c_str(), mystring.size(),
                   substring.c_str(), substring.size(),
                   0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about iterating the string ,stop each time the character matches the first character of the sub string, then look if the counter is small enough for the substring to fit , and if so , iterate in a sub loop character by character to find a match?

Comment: if someone could post some code that would be helpful. I am avoiding comparing chars because it's messy and not necessary.

Comment: If I could use a string as a delimiter, I think that would help, but I think delimeters are reserved for chars.

Comment: you can't compare strings without eventually compare characters.

Answer (score 0):

The function can be written the following way

```
std::string::size_type GetIndex( const std::string &myString, 
                                 const std::string &subString )
{
    if ( myString.size() < subString.size() ) return std::string::npos;
    if ( myString.substr( 0, subString.size() ) == subString ) return 0;

    std::string::size_type n = GetIndex( myString.substr( 1 ), subString );

    return ( n == std::string::npos ) ? std::string::npos : n + 1;
}
```

Here is a demonstartive program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string::size_type GetIndex( const std::string &myString, 
                                 const std::string &subString )
{
    if ( myString.size() < subString.size() ) return std::string::npos;
    if ( myString.substr( 0, subString.size() ) == subString ) return 0;

    std::string::size_type n = GetIndex( myString.substr( 1 ), subString );

    return ( n == std::string::npos ) ? std::string::npos : n + 1;
}                                 

int main()
{
    std::string::size_type n = GetIndex( "Hello World", "World" );

    if ( n != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << "The substring is found at position " << n  << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The substring is not found" << std::endl;
    }

    n = GetIndex( "Hello C", "C++" );

    if ( n != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << "The substring is found at position " << n  << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The substring is not found" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
The substring is found at position 6
The substring is not found
```

If you want you may substitute type `std::string::size_type` for `int` and `std::string::npos` for `-1`.:)